# how to ask if a JButton is part of a JButton array?

Tags: java, swing

how can ask if a certain button from the array belongs to the matriz?
this for example.

```
JButton matrix = new JButton[8][8];
```

how can ask if a certain button from the array belongs to the matriz?
this for example.

```
matrix[i+2][j-1]
```

any help will greatly appreciated i am really new to java and nothing of this was explained to me. So i have been struggling a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple nested for loop?

```
public boolean hasButton(JButton button)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
        if(matrix[i] != null) for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(button == matrix[i][j]) return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to only give the ActionListener (or better AbstractAction) for the array type of buttons to the JButtons that are in fact *in* the array. In other words, separate ActionListeners or AbstractActions for separate behaviors. Divide and conquer!

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GuiEg extends JPanel {
   private static final String[][] BUTTON_TXTS = { 
      { "1", "2", "3" },
      { "4", "5", "6" }, 
      { "7", "8", "9" }, 
      { "", "0", "" } };
   private JButton[][] calcButtons = new JButton[BUTTON_TXTS.length][BUTTON_TXTS[0].length];

   public GuiEg() {
      // get rid of magic numbers
      setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
      add(createEastPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(createCenterPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   private JComponent createEastPanel() {
      JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
      eastPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Start") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Start has been pressed!");
         }
      }));
      eastPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Stop") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Stop has been pressed!");
         }
      }));
      eastPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Pause") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Pause has been pressed!");
         }
      }));
      eastPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Exit") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(GuiEg.this);
            win.dispose();
         }
      }));
      return eastPanel;
   }

   private JComponent createCenterPanel() {
      int rows = BUTTON_TXTS.length;
      int cols = BUTTON_TXTS[0].length;
      JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows , cols));
      ActionListener calcListener = new CalcListener(); 
      for (int r = 0; r < BUTTON_TXTS.length; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < BUTTON_TXTS[r].length; c++) {
            String text = BUTTON_TXTS[r][c];
            if (!text.isEmpty()) {
               calcButtons[r][c] = new JButton(text);
               calcButtons[r][c].addActionListener(calcListener);
               centerPanel.add(calcButtons[r][c]);
            } else {
               centerPanel.add(new JLabel());
            }
         }
      }
      return centerPanel;
   }

   private class CalcListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         System.out.println(evt.getActionCommand() + " button pressed!");
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      GuiEg mainPanel = new GuiEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GuiEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```